# Is declaring variable with type inference as effective as "classical way" of initializing variable with parenthesis after variable name?

Tags: c++, constructor, type-inference

It would be nice to be able to easily text search in my codebase for places where is constructor of some object called. Here comes pattern bellow. Instead of classical:

1. `Object val( a, b );`

It would be nice to use everywhere:

2. `auto val = Object( a, b );`

That way I can use simple text search for `"Object("` and get list of places where I am calling constructor of `Object`. It's also less syntacticaly ambiguous and therefore easier to make simple tools to automate some code transformations. It elegantly avoids "most vexing parse" issues too.

My only concern is about possible impact on performance. Is case 2) as fast a as case 1)? (If we can assume that `Object` has properly defined move constructor and move assignment operator and basic compiler optimizations are enabled.)

Comment: Rather than optimizing your code for the tools, you could try to use tools that work with your code, such as clang-query.

Comment: Note that you can use uniform initialization since C++11 to avoid most vexing parse problem.

Comment: You could search for `Object` and `(` with a single token in between

Comment: While there will be no performance impact in any compilers I know, the technique itself is contradictory to me. Without knowing the code, someone will be left to guess what the `Object` is - is it a free-standing function or a constructor? Granted, in IDE's it's a matter of a single jump, but it's still a jump and you loose context. I prefer classic syntax here.

Comment: @SergeyA: interesting viewpoint. Are there any semantic difference which make ability to distinguish object constructor call and function returning object important for reasoning about code? At first sight it seems to me that constructor of object behaves like function returning that object and therefore for observer at callside constructor of object and function returning object are interchangable without affecting understanding of code.

Comment: @SergeyA: I mean, its a matter of choosing words more than there is any difference between function and constructor call. That thing which is named "constructor of Object" can be named also "function with name Object returning type Object". Someone may argue that C++ does not allow to have same function and type name. Yes. But there is workaround to do that. C++ have special syntactic sugar (constructor) with which you can effectively make "function with name Object returning type Object". So, constructor CAN be seen as free standing function. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pre C++17, it is possible, although unlikely, that you would get a performance penalty due to an extra copy or move.  Even C++98 allowed implementations to remove such copies even if they would produce side-effects, and almost all compilers have implemented this optimization for a long time -- especially in optimized builds.

Post C++-17, copy elision is guaranteed.  You aren't even required to have a copy or move constructor for this to work, so you shouldn't see any difference.

Comment: The assignment operator is not required though.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Agreed.  The question involves an initialization and not an assignment.

Comment: *"to remove such copies even if they would produce side-effects"*, doesn't that break the semantics, in the case of side-effects?

Comment: @A.S.H: Absolutely, but the C++ committee decided that this optimization was important enough to allow it even if it breaks the semantics.

Comment: @A.S.H : In practise, the side effect of a copy-constructor/destructor pair is usually a no-op, or output to a logfile, both of which are safe to optimize.  But yes, if your program depends on copy-constructor/destructor pairs *not* being eliminated, it is broken.

Comment: I see the point. But I am surprised. I thought that syntax and semantics are usually the top-level untouchables, before anyone thinking of optimization. This is puzzling me. I would understand if we say that the compiler checks for side effects before optimizing away, but saying it can do that without any such rule, is changing the semantics of the language.

Comment: @A.S.H: Maybe my use of the word "optimization" is confusing.  This is more like implementation-specific behavior.  Pre C++17, an implementation was allowed to choose whether or not to actually do the copy or move, but the copy/move constructor was still required to be accessible.

Comment: C++ allowed copy ellision in this case. C++17 mandates it. This is an example of very rare optimization which happens on the frontend and changes program semantic.

Comment: @SergeyA So if I understand, this feature mandated in C++17 states explicitly this change of semantic, in which case everything is in order.